# ReduxForm: adding map input from a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a Redux Form component which has a Google Maps child component called PlotMap. The child component passes map input back as an object in a callback. I would like to include this map input object in the form data when it's submitted. How do I do that? Do I use a hidden field? The wondrous workings of Redux Form are opaque to me, so I am not sure where to append the object.

PlotForm component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import * as actions from '../../actions';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import PlotMap from './plotMap';

const renderField = ({
    input,
    label,
    type,
    meta: { touched, error, warning }
}) => (
    <fieldset className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor={input.name}>{label}</label>
        <input className="form-control" {...input} type={type} />
        {touched && error && <span className="text-danger">{error}</span>}
    </fieldset>
);

class PlotForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleFormSubmit(props) {
        this.props.addPlot(props);
    }

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
        const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        return (
            <div className="form-container text-center">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
                    <Field
                        name="name"
                        component={renderField}
                        type="text"
                        label="Plot Name"
                    />
                    {user &&
                        user.role === 3 && (
                            <Field
                                name="company"
                                component={renderField}
                                type="text"
                                label="Company"
                            />
                        )}
                    <Field
                        name="grower"
                        component={renderField}
                        type="text"
                        label="Grower"
                    />
                    <Field
                        name="variety"
                        component={renderField}
                        type="text"
                        label="Variety"
                    />
                    <Field
                        name="variety2"
                        component={renderField}
                        type="text"
                        label="Variety 2"
                    />
                    <Field
                        name="planted"
                        component={renderField}
                        type="date"
                        label="Date Planted"
                    />
                    <hr />
                    <PlotMap getGeoJSON={GeoJSON => console.log(GeoJSON)} />
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <span>
                            <label>&nbsp;</label>
                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                                Add Plot
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <hr />
                <div>
                    {this.props.errorMessage &&
                        this.props.errorMessage.plots && (
                            <div className="error-container">
                                Oops! {this.props.errorMessage.plots}
                            </div>
                        )}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        errorMessage: state.plots.error
    };
}

PlotForm = reduxForm({ form: 'plot', validate })(PlotForm);
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(PlotForm);
```

PlotMap component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const { compose, withProps } = require('recompose');
const { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap } = require('react-google-maps');
const {
    DrawingManager
} = require('react-google-maps/lib/components/drawing/DrawingManager');

const editTrack = polygon => {
    let GeoJSON = {
        type: 'Feature',
        geometry: {
            type: 'Polygon',
            coordinates: []
        },
        properties: {}
    };
    for (let point of polygon.getPath().getArray()) {
        GeoJSON.geometry.coordinates.push([point.lng(), point.lat()]);
    }
    return GeoJSON;
};

const PlotMap = compose(
    withProps({
        googleMapURL:
            'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places',
        loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
        containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
        mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
    }),
    withScriptjs,
    withGoogleMap
)(props => (
    <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={8}
        defaultCenter={new google.maps.LatLng(32.095, 35.398)}>
        <DrawingManager
            onPolygonComplete={polygon => {
                polygon.setEditable(true);
                props.getGeoJSON(editTrack(polygon));
                google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), 'insert_at', function(
                    index,
                    obj
                ) {
                    props.getGeoJSON(editTrack(polygon));
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), 'set_at', function(
                    index,
                    obj
                ) {
                    props.getGeoJSON(editTrack(polygon));
                });
            }}
            defaultDrawingMode={google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON}
            defaultOptions={{
                drawingControl: true,
                drawingControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                    drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON]
                }
            }}
        />
    </GoogleMap>
));

export default PlotMap;
```

Comment: I need more info about the interface (props) of PlotMap.

Comment: Move `const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));` to `componentWillMount()` or the constructor, you don't to call it on each render. Better yet, create a redux middleware that handles this for, and load it to the store.

Comment: thanks,@OriDrori. Added the code for PlotMap. It basically goes through the polygon object when it's first created and then when it is edited, and fires the callback, creating and returning a new GeoJSON object.

Comment: One problem - since you don't have a prop to initialize/update the PlotMap from the state, the store and map might diverge when you refresh the page, or re hydrate the store from a saved state.

Comment: what version of redux-form are you using?

Comment: I'm using 7.0.4

Comment: Can you provide a reference for creating a redux middleware to get the user and load into the store?

Comment: You'll have to provide more data about why and how you are using `user` (for example - why is user in localStorage at all, where do you save it to localStorage, etc...) to give a good answer. Open a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, you can pass a stateless function ("renderField") as a the `component` prop to a `Field`. You can wrap the `PlotMap` in a function, and connect only the `onChange` handler to `getGeoJSON`.

The `onChange` method is described as:

> A callback that will be called whenever an onChange event is fired
>   from the underlying input.

This callback notifies redux-form that the field content has change, and this updates the redux store. Instead of calling it using the `onChange` event, you can call it manually, and pass the data.

**Example redux-form(untested):**

```
<Field name="plotMap" component={({ input }) => (
  <PlotMap getGeoJSON={input.onChange} />
)}/>
```

Comment: Could you explain how the input.onChange parameter works here?

Comment: Also, when the form is submitted, will the GeoJSON object be accessible as req.body.plotMap?

Comment: I'll add some info. It will, since it's a standard redux-form field.